# Authorize.net Integration In Php

Tags: php, annotations, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am integrating Authorize.net payment integration for my website. Integrate demo from site : http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions
I am trying to integrate demo with Authorize.net SDK. SDK downloaded from : https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/releases

**Error Message**

> Warning:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\sample-code-php-master\sdk-php-1.9.3/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\sample-code-php-master\sdk-php-1.9.3\autoload.php
>   on line 16
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\sample-code-php-master\sdk-php-1.9.3/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/Type.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\sample-code-php-master\sdk-php-1.9.3\autoload.php
>   on line 16
>
> Fatal error: Class 'JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\sample-code-php-master\sdk-php-1.9.3\lib\net\authorize\util\SensitiveDataConfigType.php
>   on line 6

I don't know how to solve it. I want to integrate it without composer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using Composer on Windows, when a global install of a library / package is done, composer stores the package in a Composer directory inside Windows' **application data folders** which by default is "C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming".

To change this folder to, for example, "C:\php\composer", create a COMPOSER_HOME environmental variable with the value set to "C:\php\composer".

Alternatively, there is custom SPL autoloader for you to reference from within your PHP file:

```
require 'path/to/anet_php_sdk/autoload.php';
```

This autoloader still requires the vendor directory and all of its dependencies to exist. However, this is a possible solution for cases where composer can't be run on a given system. You can run composer locally or on another system to build the directory, then copy the vendor directory to the desired system.